# Having separate Controller/Views for each Tab?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an application in Asp.NET MVC. The main page will consist of a couple of tabs, for example, Students & Courses.

There will be a Student model and Course model.  I'd like to have a Controller for each that would contain New, Edit, Delete Actions.  The front end will look similar to this..

[image]

I'd like to use partial views within the body of each tab. Taking the first tab as an example, when the page loads it will display a list of Students in the tab body as a partial view. On clicking 'Add Student' within this partial view it will call an Action in the Student Controller and then return and display a partial view in the tab body with a form to create a new Student.  On posting this form it will then again show the Student list partial view in the tab body.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or suggest a clean approach to achieve this?

A thought I had would be to have a partial view for each Action, for example:

```
<div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:10px;">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="page-config-tab">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Student/_List.cshtml")
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Student/_Add.cshtml")
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Student/_Edit.cshtml")
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="candidates-tab">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Course/_List.cshtml")
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Course/_Add.cshtml")
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Course/_Edit.cshtml")
    </div>
</div>
```

And when a button is clicked, I will use Jquery to Hide/Show the relevant partial view in a div before calling the Action in the Controller?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use jquery vs say React or Angular?

Comment: To be honest I've yet to learn React or Angular but I'm familiar with Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to call the necessary action which returns the correct partial view. Rendering them all on page load is wasteful since only 1 partial view will be displayed at a time.
Your initial HTML should looks like the following, only rendering the view you need:

```
<div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:10px;">
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="page-config-tab">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Student/_List.cshtml")
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="candidates-tab"></div>
```

Then, add a script block:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#addStudentBtn').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Student")',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#page-config-tab').html(data); // 'data' will be your partial view
                }
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've shown you a bare-minimum example for adding a student, you can use this general approach for each action.

P.S. looks like you're using bootstrap - they have event handlers you can use when changing tabs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs-events